# Chartkick Error - SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, chartkick

I'm trying to include chart into my Rails APP, but getting this error:

[image]

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'chartkick', '~> 1.2.4'
gem 'groupdate', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'active_median', '~> 0.1.0'
```

**Controller**

```
@commits = Bitbucket.all
```

**View**

```
JS - <%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
CHART - <%= line_chart @commits.group_by_day(:date, format: "%Y-%m-%d").count %>
```

Anyone know where is problem?

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error don't you think `Connection adapter not supported: SQLite`

Comment: Yeah it could be clear, but don't know the solution for that.
I tried to update SQL to `1.3.4` but my entire app crushed..

Comment: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/issues/62

Comment: Don't think there is a solution to it yet

Comment: Hmmm, not supported. Ok moving it to PostgresSQL.. Thanks